# Convert emoji coming as uf-8 hex in text file back to character

Tags: ios, utf-8, whatsapp

I have imported whatsapp chat in email and when I opened it contains characters like this =F0=9F=94=A9 for emoji which is utf-8 string. Can someone please tell me how can I convert these characters back to emoji while showing in iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

I am face same type of issue for emoji text and i found solution that i mention here.

```
-(NSString *)decodeSmiley:(NSString *)strData
{
    if(strData != nil)
    {
        NSData *data = [strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        return decodedString;

    }

    return @"";
}
```

For encoding

```
-(NSString *)encodeSmiley:(NSString *)strData
{
    if(strData != nil)
    {
        NSData *data = [strData dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *base64Encoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        return base64Encoded;
    }

    return @"";
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code for decodeSmiley but I got the same string with utf-8 characters in it

Comment: Can you please try it with this string to see if shows smileys or not, String = "I woke up &
started searching with him.=F0=9F=98=9D

=F0=9F=98=89=F0=9F=98=9C=F0=9F=98=86=F0=9F=98=9D=F0=9F=98=82=F0=9F=98=82=F0=9F=
=98=9D=F0=9F=98=86=F0=9F=98=9C

Happy Month end =F0=9F=98=9C"